# Scala 2.13.1 Unable to use macros

Tags: scala, macros

I am unable to use **macros** in scala `2.13.1`.

I keep getting the following error:

```
object blackbox is not a member of package scala.reflect.macros
```

This obviously isn't true, because scala 2.13.1 actually has these blackbox. 
What am I not doing right?

**Hello.scala**

```
package example.core

import example.macros.MacroLibrary

object Hello extends App {
  MacroLibrary.hello()
}
```

**MacroLibrary.scala**

```
package example.macros

// This line throws errors
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object MacroLibrary {
  def hello_impl(c: blackbox.Context)(): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    c.Expr(q"""println("Hello World")""")
  }

  def hello(): Unit = macro hello_impl
}
```

**build.sbt**

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
```

**Error**

```
object blackbox is not a member of package scala.reflect.macros
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not in the standard library, but in separate `scala-reflect`, which needs to be added as a dependency in `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
```

You can see that from [`Context` documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.1/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/macros/blackbox/Context.html) having "Scala Reflection Library" in the top left.

Comment: Where is this documented? I couldn't find it in the official docs.

Comment: That's why I added the last line.